# Ubuntu SSH IP Address Issues

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, ssh

I plan on using a newly acquired desktop tower as a server, and I would like to start by setting up SSH service. So far I have had no success and I believe the problem is that the IP for my computer is controlled by the apartment complex I live in and therefore I seem to have restricted control (i.e. no control) over port binding.

Is there any workaround for this?

(P.s. I'm still learning as I go, so any offhand advice in your answer will also be much appreciated!)

Edit 1:

`sshd_config`:

```
# Package generated configuration file
# See the sshd_config(5) manpage for details

# What ports, IPs and protocols we listen for, just picked a port at random
# because none were working
Port 380
# Use these options to restrict which interfaces/protocols sshd will bind to
#ListenAddress ::
ListenAddress  [IP Address of Apartment Complex]
Protocol 2
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
#Privilege Separation is turned on for security
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin no
StrictModes yes

RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys

# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
IgnoreRhosts yes
# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh_known_hosts
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
HostbasedAuthentication no
# Uncomment if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for RhostsRSAAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts yes

# To enable empty passwords, change to yes (NOT RECOMMENDED)
PermitEmptyPasswords yes

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Change to no to disable tunnelled clear text passwords
PasswordAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes

X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no

#MaxStartups 10:30:60
#Banner /etc/issue.net

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes
```

Output of `sudo systemctl start ssh`:

```
Job for ssh.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status ssh.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Output of `systemctl status ssh.service`:

```
ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-06-05 22:15:30 PDT; 14s ago
   Process: 2288 ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Process: 6579 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS (code=exited, status=255)
 Main PID: 6579 (code=exited, status=255)

Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: ssh.service: Unit entered failed state.
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: ssh.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Truncated output of 'journalctl -xe`:

```
Unit ssh.service has begun starting up.
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case sshd[6579]: error: Bind to port 380 on [IP Address of My Apartment Complex] failed: Cannot assign requested address.
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case sshd[6579]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: ssh.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Jun 05 22:15:30 Case systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
-- Subject: Unit ssh.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit ssh.service has failed.
```

Other details:

I am wired into a wireless router which is, in turn, wired into the wall (hence why the IP address is that of the apartment complex)

Hope that's enough details!

Comment: So... you want to SSH from outside, but you don't have a public IP or a way to forward ports on your apartment router?

Comment: What have you done and what was the result? Please add all details [to your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/922565/edit). Blocking SSH packets inside a home LAN is possible but rare.

Comment: You set the `ListenAddress` in the config file to the `IP Address of Apartment Complex`; but that is not the address of your machine. Thus `sshd`does not know what to do and does not start. So, first set the `ListenAddress` to the "real" address of your machine (or `0.0.0.0`to listen on any address of your machine), to get `sshd`started. If you want to access it from the outside (Internet), you have to ask your network administrator to activate IP forwarding in the NAT router.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an apartment building that provides wifi you are lucky indeed.  If so, chances are very good that you have a DHCP provided IP Address.  This means that every time you reboot or shut down your server you will get a new connection lease and probably a different IP address.  However, if this inconvenience is not a huge problem for you, you can just configure SSH per the documentation that is all over the place on this site.

SSHD will work with any IP address that is assigned to the server, including unrouteable addresses and local loopback.  Naturally, if you want to ssh in from the Internet, you will need to have an IP that is reachable from outside your LAN.  Running speedtest from their web site will help determine what that IP is.

As a starting point, check to see what your current IP address (if any) is by typing

```
ifconfig -a
```

Setting up sshd is very easy.  A little less easy depending on how secure you want access to your server to be.  Basic ssh works pretty much out of the box on Ubuntu 16.04

To test to see if sshd is working, irrespective of a network connection, type

```
ssh localhost
```

This will allow you to log on to your server and will verify that sshd is indeed running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Reverse SSH Tunneling for accessing you box behind a NAT.